# When Joe Blake travels to Berlin, do those jets really exist?

Tags: the-man-in-the-high-castle

Are those jets that can be seen in *The Man in the High Castle* when Joe Blake travels to Berlin for real? For a second I thought they were like Concordes but then I realised they were not. If no, then the VFX used is really great.

[image]

Comment: To make sure, you're not asking if those jets actually exist in reality, like those specific plane models existing, but if they used real jets for *filming*?

Comment: It would be nice if you could answer both

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There were only two commercial SST, the Concorde and the Tupolev Tu-144.

This is neither of those, the tails and cockpit windows are different, and the Nazi aircraft has fewer exit doors than the real-life aircraft.

## So, it's a Special Effect (CGI)

Here's a shot of the effect actually being filmed

[image]

There is a YouTube video from Zoic Studios who do the effects. This can be seen at 1.14

---

**Concorde**

[image]

The last Concorde airbody is currently at Aerospace Bristol, a museum dedicated to the region's involvement in air travel, in the UK.

**Tu-144**

[image]

Comment: Nice find & wow, they didn't even bother building the door - that had to make the CGI lighting guys work harder to get it right as people crossed the threshold. btw, I'd love to show you comparative photos from stuff I've worked on... but unfortunately it's a 'sackable' offence :/

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not a real plane, it's CGI.

The design looks like a hybrid of the rather famous [Concorde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concorde_aircraft_histories)

[image]

& the less famous & rather more crash-prone [Tupolev TU-144](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupolev_Tu-144)

[image]

Perhaps a case of 'parallel evolution' or even just 'spying'.
Both planes first flew in 1969.

Germany already had the jet engine in the mid-40s (in our timeline ;) as a parallel evolution to the [Whittle engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_Whittle) developed by the Allies, before & during the war.
The [Messerschmidt Me 262](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messerschmitt_Me_262) saw service before the end of WWII.

Let's just assume the show's writers saw fit to bring that development forward a little - it helps shorten the wait between character moves very nicely.